# CppAD with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I can't seem to find any great documentation on how to use Eigen with CppAD. The specific problem that I would like to see addressed is how to multiply a matrix of doubles with a matrix of `CppAD::AD<double>`. Here is a MWE that does not compile:

```
#include "cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp"
#include "Eigen/Dense"

int main() {

    using ADdouble= CppAD::AD<double>;

    const int n = 3;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n> A = Eigen::Matrix<double, n, n>::Zero();
    Eigen::Matrix<ADdouble, n, n> B = Eigen::Matrix<ADdouble, n, n>::Zero();
    Eigen::Matrix<ADdouble, n, n> C = A * B;
    return 0;
}
```

I was under the impression that I simply needed to include

`#include "cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp"`

and that that would take care of these issues.

---

### EDIT

Upon further inspection, the [documentation](https://www.coin-or.org/CppAD/Doc/cppad_eigen.hpp.htm) provides two examples:

1. https://www.coin-or.org/CppAD/Doc/eigen_array.cpp.htm
2. https://www.coin-or.org/CppAD/Doc/eigen_det.cpp.htm

But neither show how to mix types.

---

### EDIT

Here is the full error message

```
C:\Users\matth\.CLion2018.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/cmake-build-debug --target tester -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target tester
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tester.dir/test.cpp.o
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/Core:463:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp:73,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h: In instantiation of 'struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >':
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:115:7:   required from 'class Eigen::internal::dense_product_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0, 3>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:147:7:   required from 'class Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0, Eigen::Dense>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:71:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:11:43:   required from here
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:29:127: error: no type named 'ReturnType' in 'struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<double, CppAD::AD<double>, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, CppAD::AD<double> > >'
   typedef typename ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename traits<LhsCleaned>::Scalar, typename traits<RhsCleaned>::Scalar>::ReturnType Scalar;
                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/Core:459:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp:73,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >':
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:115:7:   required from 'class Eigen::internal::dense_product_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0, 3>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:147:7:   required from 'class Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0, Eigen::Dense>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:71:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:11:43:   required from here
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:83:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::coeff' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::coeff;
                 ^~~~~
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:84:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::coeffByOuterInner' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::coeffByOuterInner;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:85:26: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::operator()' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::operator();
                          ^
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:86:26: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::operator[]' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::operator[];
                          ^
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:87:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::x' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::x;
                 ^
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:88:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::y' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::y;
                 ^
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:89:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::z' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::z;
                 ^
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:90:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}::w' in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>, 0>}'
     using Base::w;
                 ^
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/Core:460:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp:73,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >':
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:115:7:   required from 'class Eigen::internal::dense_product_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0, 3>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:147:7:   required from 'class Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0, Eigen::Dense>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:71:7:   required from 'class Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0>'
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:11:43:   required from here
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:75:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}::coeff' in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}'
     using Base::coeff;
                 ^~~~~
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:78:17: error: no members matching 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}::eval' in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}'
     using Base::eval;
                 ^~~~
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:79:25: error: no members matching 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}::operator-' in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}'
     using Base::operator-;
                         ^
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:82:25: error: no members matching 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}::operator*=' in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}'
     using Base::operator*=;
                         ^~
/cygdrive/c/Dropbox/android/TrajectoryOptimization/app/libs/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:83:25: error: no members matching 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}::operator/=' in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 3>, 0> >}'
     using Base::operator/=;
                         ^~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/tester.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/tester.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/tester.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/tester.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: tester] Error 2
```

---

### EDIT

As per the suggested answers, I created the header `mixed_types.h`:

```
#ifndef MIXED_TYPES_HEADER
#define MIXED_TYPES_HEADER

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <cppad/cppad.hpp>

namespace Eigen {

template<typename S, typename BinOp>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<CppAD::AD<S>, S, BinOp> {
    typedef CppAD::AD<S> ReturnType;
};

template<typename S, typename BinOp>
struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<S, CppAD::AD<S>, BinOp> {
    typedef CppAD::AD<S> ReturnType;
};

}

#endif /* MIXED_TYPES_HEADER */
```

and I tried using this in a product of the form

```
A = B * C
```

where the `Scalar` type of `A` and `B` is `CppAD::AD<double>`, and the `Scalar` type of `C` is `double`. However, this generates a very long compiler error of the form:

```
In file included from ../src\main\cpp/mixed_types.h:4:
In file included from ../../../../libs/include\Eigen/Core:516:
../../../../libs/include\Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:999:13: error: no matching member function for call to 'madd'
            EIGEN_GEBP_ONESTEP(0);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../libs/include\Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h:980:22: note: expanded from macro 'EIGEN_GEBP_ONESTEP'
              traits.madd(A0, B_0, C0, T0); \
              ~~~~~~~^~~~
../../../../libs/include\Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralMatrixMatrix.h:194:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<CppAD::AD<double>, double, long, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<CppAD::AD<double>, long, 0, 0>, 2, 4, false, false>::operator()' requested here
          gebp(res.getSubMapper(i2, j2), blockA, blockB, actual_mc, actual_kc, actual_nc, alpha);
          ^
../../../../libs/include\Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralMatrixMatrix.h:226:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::general_matrix_matrix_product<long, CppAD::AD<double>, 0, false, double, 0, false, 0>::run' requested here
    Gemm::run(rows, cols, m_lhs.cols(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't verify right now, but it seems the code you need is in **eigen_mat_mul.hpp**.

Have a look a the file [here](https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD/blob/master/cppad/example/eigen_mat_mul.hpp).

Comment: I saw that. There is also a file `mat_mul.hpp` which seems to redefine everything already in ` eigen_mat_mul.hpp`. It is just not clear to me how to use either of these files

Comment: I simplified the example even further and attached the error

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Surprisingly, a cast up from the raw type `double` to `CppAD::AD<double>` seems to do the trick. For example, this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cppad/cppad.hpp>
#include <cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template<typename T>
using Vector = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;

int main() {

    /* Types and sizes */
    using ADdouble = CppAD::AD<double>;
    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 3;

    /* Define the independent variable that we will be differentiating with respect to */
    Vector<ADdouble> X = Vector<ADdouble>::Ones(cols);
    CppAD::Independent(X);

    /* Now define the function. The function is simply a matrix multiplication */
    Eigen::Matrix<double, rows, cols> A = Eigen::Matrix<double, rows, cols>::Random();
    Vector<ADdouble> Y = A.cast<ADdouble>() * X;
    CppAD::ADFun<double> f(X, Y);

    /* Now define the value of X that we want to evaluate the jacobian at */
    Vector<double> x = Vector<double>::Random(cols);

    /* Compute the jacobian and compare to the know value */
    Vector<double> jac = f.Jacobian(x);

    /* We are going to map the jacobian back to a matrix so that it is easier to visualize.
     * Note that CppAD seems to use row major format, while Eigen defaults to
     * column major */
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, rows, cols, Eigen::RowMajor>> Jac(jac.data());
    std::cout << "CppAD Jacobian: " << std::endl << Jac << std::endl << std::endl;

    /* Now compare to the know jacobian, which is simply "A" */
    std::cout << "Known Jacobian: " << std::endl << A << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
CppAD Jacobian: 
 0.380002 -0.484536 -0.862444
0.0108368 -0.585236 -0.180186
 0.182981  0.252524  0.759988
  0.10957 -0.319746 -0.361039
-0.243142  0.687704  0.961136

Known Jacobian: 
 0.380002 -0.484536 -0.862444
0.0108368 -0.585236 -0.180186
 0.182981  0.252524  0.759988
  0.10957 -0.319746 -0.361039
-0.243142  0.687704  0.961136
```

However, I am not sure if this will always work. It seems suspect to me because the case must be initializing some properties for the constant matrices of type `double`. I would guess that there is technically some undefined behavior here. It would be great if an Eigen/CppAD dev could comment.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to specialize `ScalarBinaryOpTraits`:

```
namespace Eigen{
  template<typename S, typename BinOp>
  struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<CppAD::AD<S>,S,BinOp>
  { typedef CppAD::AD<S> ReturnType; };
  template<typename S, typename BinOp>
  struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<S,CppAD::AD<S>,BinOp>
  { typedef CppAD::AD<S> ReturnType; };
}
```

Of course, this only works if there are implementations for `operator*(double,CppAD::AD<double>)` and `operator*(CppAD::AD<double>,double)`.

Casting the `double` matrix to `CppAD::AD<double>` works as well, but requires to make a more expensive `CppAD::AD<double>*CppAD::AD<double>` product instead of a `double*CppAD::AD<double>` product every time.

Comment: Thanks chtz. I will try to implement this tomorrow

Comment: I tried this, but as I show in the update, this leads to compiler errors. I tried rearranging the order of the `includes`, but that did not help.

Comment: It seems that the error is indicating that I did not overload the addition operator, but it seems to me that the templated form you suggested should do that right?